# C# Session_OnStart analog for Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

In my Java application (Spring MVC+Spring Security) i need to put into session some info once time per user after authorization. In C# I used for that  `Session_OnStart` event in `Global.asax`. Are there some analogs for that in Spring?

I tried to use `ApplicationListener<AuthenticationSuccessEvent>`,  but got error:

> Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread

Answer (score 1):

You can try to define a method in the session scope bean and mark it as @PostConstruct. When the bean is ready the method is invoked.

UPDATE
or use

```
public class MyLoginSuccessfullHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, 
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
//your code
}
```

and define

```
<beans:bean id="usernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">



        <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="yourSuccessHandlerBean"/>
    </beans:bean>
```